# Do any of the FFMPEG libraries have a method for determining the frame type (I, P or B) of a frame WITHOUT first decoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

Every once and a while this comes up and I've never been able to find a good solution but I figured I'd ask the experts: is there a video frame parser in FFMPEG that can determine frame type WITHOUT resorting to decoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each codec has its particular syntax, and the decoder is the bespoke component that can work with that syntax. Now, is there an operational mode where the decoders analyze and log surface level parameters of the payload without entering the codepath to generate raster? In general, no.

There is a `-debug` option (http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Codec-Options), which when set, certain decoders, mainly the native MPEG decoders, will log some metadata, but this will invoke the decoder. For modern codecs, there's the `trace_headers` [bitstream filter](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#trace_005fheaders) which can be used in streamcopy mode. This will parse and print all the parameter sets and slice headers. You can dump these to file and inspect them.